# show html div if count of numbers equal 16 (cc verfication)

Tags: javascript

I am beginner with javascript.

I am trying to make something with javascript.

But I have ended up with a lot of inoperative codes

This is my html code

```
<input name="cc_number">

<div id="hidee" style="display:none">
<input name="cvv2">
</div>
```

I am trying to make it shown by javascript, if the number of chars in the "cc_number input" is 16

My idea is counting characters and make a condition if they equals 16 then show the div.

but I failed to build the code.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried to far? We're not going to write your code for you.

Comment: your markup is wrong. No closing tags, no input type on fields, naming is also not good.

Comment: @phobos this is just an example, my code is too long&complex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to hook a handler on keyup of the input field:

```
<input name="cc_number" onkeyup="showDiv(this)">

<div id="hidee" style="display:none">
<input name="cvv2">
</div>

<script>
  function showDiv(src) {
    document.getElementById("hidee").style.display =
      src.value.length==16 ? "block" : "none";
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
var number = document.getElementById('cc_number');
var hidee = document.getElementById('hidee');

number.onkeyup = function () {
    if (this.value.length >= 16)
        hidee.style.display = 'block';
    else
        hidee.style.display = 'none';
};
```

I also added an `id` to your `cc_number` `div` so it can be more easily selected.

```
<input id="cc_number" name="cc_number">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this *nonobtrusive* solution:

**Javascript**:

```
document.getElementsByName("cc_number")[0].onkeyup = function(){
    if(this.value.length>=16)
        document.getElementById("hidee").style.display ="block";
    else
        document.getElementById("hidee").style.display ="none";
}
```

**Markup**:

```
<input name="cc_number" />

<div id="hidee" style="display:none">
    <input name="cvv2" />
</div>
```

**jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/PhyVQ/

Answer (score 0):

Probably your best bet is a little jQuery:

```
$('input[name="cc_number"]').on('keyup', function() {
    if($(this).val().length==16){
        $('#hidee').show();
    } else {
        $('#hidee').hide();
    }
});
```

Which just attaches a listener (keyup in the example), and on that event checks the value's length.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but if the question isn't tagged/or mentions jQuery, only use plain javascript answers (remember not everyone uses jQuery)